# CrystalReport Formulai Error- 'A number is required here. Details: errorKind'

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to use below formula in crystal report but im getting the below error when the report is rendered

```
Error in formula OpenSafeDoors: 'Local stringVar result; ' A number is required here.   
Details: errorKind
```

The formula is given below

```
Local stringVar result;
If IsNull({dtEnrolledUserReport.Open Safe Doors}) or {dtEnrolledUserReport.Open Safe  
Doors}=""
 Then
   result:='N'
 Else
   result:='Y';
 result;
```

Im using another formula with same logic but with different column name.Im not getting any error there.

Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

```
Local stringVar result;
If IsNull({dtEnrolledUserReport.Open Safe Doors}) or {dtEnrolledUserReport.Open Safe  
Doors}=""
 Then
   result:="N"
 Else
   result:="Y"
```

Comment: What us the data type of `dtEnrolledUserReport.Open Safe Doors` ??

Comment: Datatype is string but the value it returns is either 0 or 1.If the value is 1 i want to print 'y' otherwise 'N'

Comment: can you try the updated answer and see whether you still get the error?

Comment: Is this your complete formula or part of it?? Because I can't see any issue at the moment

Comment: Yes..when i changed the stringVar to numberVar same error is still coming.Any idea??

Comment: What I am not sure is why you have `result;` after else part. (The last line)??

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting issue at variable try below way.

```
If IsNull({dtEnrolledUserReport.Open Safe Doors}) or {dtEnrolledUserReport.Open Safe  
Doors}=""
 Then
   'N'
 Else
   'Y';
```